# join & f.write behaviour not as expected

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a query running in SQL, which is returning the results in to a variable via a loop then punting that in to an HTML file. When I test this by printing to the console in Jupyter Notebook it prints as expected, the next 30 days of the calendar in order of date.

However, when I tell it to join the data using

```
dates = ''.join(variable)
```

it seems to not only reorder the dates so that the 13th of August sits oddly before the 13th of July, but it repeats the date div's 4 times in the page. See below for full code;

```
from os import getenv
import pyodbc
import os

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=MYVM\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=MyTables;UID=test;PWD=t')

cursor = cnxn.cursor() #makes connection
cursor.execute('DECLARE @today as date SET @today = GetDate() SELECT style112, day, month, year, dayofweek, showroom_name, isbusy from ShowroomCal where Date Between @today and dateadd(month,1,@today) order by style112') #runs statement


while row is not None:
    inset = inset + ['<div class="'+ str(row.isbusy) + '"><a href="#" id="' + str(row.style112) + '" onclick="parent.updateField(field38, ' + str(row.style112) + ');">' + str(row.day) + '</a></div>']
    row = cursor.fetchone()



dates = ''.join(inset)    
f = open("C:\\tes.html",'r') # open file with read permissions
filedata = f.read() # read contents
f.close() # closes file
filedata = filedata.replace("{inset}", dates) 

#os.remove("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\cal\\tes.html")



f = open("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\cal\\tes.html",'w') 
f.write(filedata) # update it replacing the previous strings 
f.close() # closes the file

cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Instead of `row is not None` just use a loop: `for row in cursor:` If `inset` is a list, don't use `inset = inset +`; rather use `inset.extend([...])` or `inset += [...]` to avoid quadratic performance degradation (you are currently executing a O(N**2) algorithm by replacing the `inset` list with a new list concatenated with the previous one, which requires a loop over all elements each time).

Comment: the `''.join()` is not special; your rows are not ordered by day, the database is free to return those in any order it pleases. Set your `ORDER BY` to sort by date.

Comment: another side note: rather than `f = open(...)` (read from or write to `f`) then `f.close()`, use the file as a context manager. `with open(...) as f:` then in the indented block read from or write to `f`. The file is closed automatically, even if there is an exception.

Comment: Last but not least, creating a cursor doesn't create a connection to the database. The `pyodbc.connect()` call made the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`''.join()` does not alter the order in any way. If you get a different order then the *database query* produced rows in a different order.

I don't think you are telling the database to order your results by date. You order by `style112`, and the database is free to order values with the same `style112` column value in any order it pleases. If `style112` doesn't include date information (as a year, month, day sequence of fixed length) and date order is important, tell the database to use a correct order! Here that'd include `year, month, day` *at the very least*.

I'd also refactor the code to avoid quadratic performance behaviour; the `inset = inset + [....]` expression has to create a new list object each time, copying across all elements from `inset` and the new list into that. When adding N elements to a list this way, Python has to execute N * N steps. For 1000 elements, that's 1 million steps to execute! Use `list.append()` to add single elements, which will reduce the workload to roughly N steps.

You can loop directly over a cursor; this is more efficient as it can buffer rows, here's `cursor.fetchone()` can't assume you'll fetch more data. A `for row in cursor:` loop is also more readable.

You can also use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) rather than string concatenation, it'll help avoid all those `str()` calls and redundancy, as well as further reduce performance issues; all those string concatenations also create and recreate a lot of intermediate string objects that you don't need to create at all.

So use this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=MYVM\SQLEXPRESS;'
    'DATABASE=MyTables;UID=test;PWD=t')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    DECLARE @today as date
    SET @today = GetDate()
    SELECT
        style112, day, month, year, dayofweek, showroom_name, isbusy
    from ShowroomCal
    where Date Between @today and dateadd(month,1,@today)
    order by year, month, day, style112
''')

inset = []
for row in cursor:
    inset.append(
        '<div class="{r.isbusy}">'
        '<a href="#" id="{r.style112}"'
        ' onclick="parent.updateField(field38, {r.style112});">'
        '{r.day}</a></div>'.format(r=row))

with open(r"C:\tes.html") as template:
    template = f.read()

html = template.format(inset=''.join(inset))

with open(r"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cal\tes.html", 'w') as output:
    output.write(html)
```

Note: if *any of your database data* was entered by your users, you **must** ensure that the data is properly escaped for inclusion in HTML *first*, or you'll leave yourself open to [XSS cross-site scripting attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). Personally, I'd use a HTML templating engine with default escaping support, such as [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

Comment: style112 is a formatted version of the date which represents as 20180713 but I'll take the rest of your answer and run with it as it seems like a more elegant and potentially ideal solution (plus, what harm can be done from ordering by the date even more)?

Comment: @C-Sway: right, that wasn't clear from the context. :-) Yes, `style112` is a YYYYMMDD-format string then ordering on that *should* have been enough.

Comment: This worked fantastically. In the end the order was working well with just the Style112 column as predicted, so I presume there must have been something about the way the do while loop was working that was lumping the dates in the wrong order.